# Getting Error "list indices must be integers or slices, not float" using folium to draw cluster points on a map

Tags: jupyter-notebook, folium

I am trying to create a cluster point on a map using. This is the code i have used but i am getting the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not float"

```
# Create map
map_clusters = folium.Map(location=[kol_lat, kol_lng], zoom_start=11)

# Set color scheme for the clusters
x = np.arange(kclusters)
ys = [i + x + (i*x)**2 for i in range(kclusters)]
colors_array = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(ys)))
rainbow = [colors.rgb2hex(i) for i in colors_array]

# Add markers to the map
markers_colors = []
for lat, lon, poi, cluster in zip(kolkata_merged['Latitude'], kolkata_merged['Longitude'], kolkata_merged['Neighbourhood'], kolkata_merged['Cluster Labels']):
    label = folium.Popup(str(poi) + ' (Cluster ' + str(cluster + 1) + ')', parse_html=True)
    map_clusters.add_child(
        folium.features.CircleMarker(
        [lat, lon],
        radius=5,
        popup=label,
        color=rainbow[cluster-1],
        fill=True,
        fill_color=rainbow[cluster-1],
        fill_opacity=0.7))

map_clusters
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no NaN values in your dataframe. 
Then try using `color=rainbow[int(cluster)-1],`